# Visual Studio 2017 cannot find typescript compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to build an application in Visual Studio that uses typescript. I followed the directions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) and installed the typescript compiler for the version the project requires (2.2). I did it with NPM

```
npm install typescript
```

I verified my installation by

```
tsc --version
```

and it returned

```
Version 2.2.2
```

which is expected. However, when I go to build my solution I keep getting the following error:

```
Your project specifies TypeScriptToolsVersion 2.2, but a matching compiler was not found. The latest available TypeScript compiler will be used (2.3). To remove this warning, install the TypeScript 2.2 SDK or update the value of TypeScriptToolsVersion.
```

I have tried Google-ing and haven't had any luck. Can someone point me down the road to a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you on an older version of Visual Studio 2017?  Make sure you are on version 15.3.

15.2 includes TypeScript 2.2, but 15.3 also allows different versions of TypeScript to be selected per project.

Once you have updated, you should be able to go to Properties/TypeScript Build for your project and ensure 2.2 is selected.

For future TypeScript updates you can install the [TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258).

Check https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017 for details. (The instructions you referred to are for Visual Studio Code.)

Comment: You may also need the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild nuget package, and you should select the version of the package that matches the typescript you are building.